# Magento homepage directory change

Tags: magento-1.9

I am a new magento user. I have facing some problems. I installed a new theme in my store. I have remove the theme by removing the theme files. But after that, I have noticed that, my home page is empty. I found that, the home page goes under "home" folder. Means that, now showing the home page in www.example.com/home link.
Please how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is the "CMS Home Page". You can find that setting in System -> Configuration -> General > Web -> Default Pages > CMS Home Page ()[image: CMS Home Page]

(sorry, i would have made a comment but i'm not allowed t do so yet ;) )

cheers

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a great first post.